Firebase Phone Auth not working on both IOS and Android
I'm in Russia at the moment and I'm trying to use Firebase Phone Auth for my project. When I a fixed number that I use on my Firebase console and insect the otp, everything works well. However, when I use an actual number, been it a number from Russia or a number from a different country I don't receive any OTP message and As such it doesn't send me to me OTP Page.
I always get this error
E/FirebaseAuth(27746): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Error code:39
E/flutter (27746): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: An internal error has occurred. [ Error code:39 ]
E/flutter (27746): #0      VerifyPhoneNumber.sendPhoneNumber.<anonymous closure> (package:HitchRide/UTILS/SERVICES/phoneAuth.dart:25:11)
E/flutter (27746): #1      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:631:29)

Can someone tell me for a fact if Firebase Phone Auth has been blocked from Russia or not. I can't seem to know the problem. The code used to work about 3-4 months ago but now it doesn't.
My App has the Firebase App Check API  and the Google Play Integrity API enabled.
